# FireStore or FireStoreClient class for Java Firestore client library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to using Google Cloud Firestore (without Firebase), just for my Cloud Functions to persist certain state data between executions.

I'm confused what's the difference between [FirestoreClient](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.v1.FirestoreClient#com_google_cloud_firestore_v1_FirestoreClient_create__) class and [FireStore](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore) class?

Both documents say they are "firestore client", oh well, one says it's "Firestore server-client", that's the same thing, right? They are all just programmatic interfaces to add, update, retrieve, and delete data in the Firestore database?

The `FireStoreClient` class seems can directly get, update, and list documents while the `FireStore` class seems to operate on DocumentReference or QueryDocumentSnapshot? Honestly I'm so confused which means what and not sure which one I should be looking at?

Btw, I really only need a database as a persistence layer between executions of my cloud function and all I'm storing are 3 key-value pair strings, but reliable persistence is important, i.e. using something like MemoryStore, even though much lightweight and easier interface, risks losing data as it's not as durable as something like FireStore. Please let me know in case I'm not making the right call here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see there is no inheritance relationship between the [FirestoreClient](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.v1.FirestoreClient) class and the [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore) interface. So a `FirestoreClient` is **not** a `Firestore`. However, both share similar methods that can help you interact with Firestore.

There are however some differences. The `Firestore` interface represents a Firestore Database entry point that provides **direct** access to Firestore Database operations. On the other hand, the `FirestoreClient` class provides the ability to make **remote** calls to the backing service. Besides that, please also note the `Firestore` interface belongs to the [com.google.cloud.firestore](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore) package, while the `FirestoreClient` class belongs to [com.google.cloud.firestore.v1](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.v1) (version 1) package.

Now, according to the use case of your app, you should choose which option fits best for performing Firestore database calls.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little unclear as to what does "make remote calls to the backing service"  mean?

Comment: When it comes to "make remote calls", it means that you aren't interacting with the service directly. You're sending a request to reach the backing service, which is a separate entity that provides the functionality. It's often referred to as a "backend service" because it runs "behind the scenes" to support the main functionality.

Comment: Could you describe exactly the difference in this particular use case as an example? What is a "backing service" or "backend service" for FireStore? The client inside Cloud Function is directly adding and retrieving object through FireStore, that's all.

Comment: If what you mean is somehow there's a service-ish wrapper around FireStore, so it exposes a different set of APIs than what FireStore already exposes...usually that would be because of the need of "high-level" versus "low-level" operations? Is there documentation explaining the rationale for both and how to make choices between them, based on use cases?

Comment: I just did a quick research, but unfortunately, I could not find any other official documentation than you already found or I already linked in my answer.

Comment: Hey unfortunately I think neither your doc or your answer here is clear at all what's the difference between the two and what people should choose....you're still yet to explain what exactly does "backing service" mean here. I'm surprised not anyone else on Internet raised this question yet.